# django order by date in datetime / extract date from datetime

Tags: sql, django, datetime

I have a model with a datetime field and I want to show the most viewed entries for the day today.

I thought I might try something like dt_published__date to extract the date from the datetime field but obviously it didn't work.

```
popular = Entry.objects.filter(type='A', is_public=True).order_by('-dt_published__date', '-views', '-dt_written', 'headline')[0:5]
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

AFAIK the `__date` syntax is not supported yet by Django. There is a [ticket](http://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/9596) open for this.

If your database has a function to extract date part then you can do this:

```
popular = Entry.objects.filter(**conditions).extra(select = 
    {'custom_dt': 'to_date(dt_published)'}).order_by('-custom_dt')
```

Comment: But won't this slow down my query?

Comment: For PostgresSQL: popular = Entry.objects.filter(**conditions).extra(select={'custom_dt': "date_trunc('day', dt_published)"}, order_by=['-custom_dt', '-views', '-dt_written', 'headline'])[0:5]. http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.0/static/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-TRUNC

Comment: In fact for PostgresSQL it's `Entry.objects.filter(**conditions).extra(select={'custom_dt': 'DATE(dt_published)'}).order_by('-custom_dt')`

Comment: As I can see this feature already been added to Django, at least on my 3.2 it works

`Payment.objects.filter(order_id=135342).order_by('paid_date__date', 'id').values_list('id', 'paid_date__date')`

Answer (score 1):

In the new Django, it should work out of the box [tested on 3.2] with Mysql 5.7

**Dataset**

```
[
  { "id": 82148, "paid_date": "2019-09-30 20:51:11"},
  { "id": 82315, "paid_date": "2019-09-30 00:00:00"},
]
```

**Query**

```
Payment.objects.filter(order_id=135342).order_by('paid_date__date', 'id').values_list('id', 'paid_date__date')
```

**Results**

```
`<QuerySet [(82148, datetime.date(2019, 9, 30)), (82315, datetime.date(2019, 9, 30))]>`
```