# Django - Sort Queryset by Date instead of Datetime

Tags: python, django, sorting

I have a model (representing a 'job') that contains a **DateTimeField** called **date_created**. I have another called **date_modified**.

I would like to sort by **-date_modified** so that the most recently modified 'jobs' are at the top of my list.  The problem is that multiple running jobs will keep getting reordered each time the timestamp gets updated.  If the **date_modified** field was sorted as if it was a **DateField**, then I could sort all 'jobs' that have been modified 'today' first, and then sort off of a second value (like date_created) so that they would not change places in the list as the timestamps are modified.

This is what I have now:

```
queryset = DataCollection.objects.all().order_by('-date_modified','-date_created')
```

I found a related article, but seems outdated with version 1.9:
[Django sorting by date(day)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38705451/django-sorting-by-dateday/38709728)

**UPDATE**

The current fix that I am looking at is this:

```
queryset = DataCollection.objects.all().extra(select = 
{'custom_dt': 'date(date_modified)'}).order_by('-custom_dt','-date_created')
```

It's most similar to what @lampslave was suggesting, but it uses the [extra](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.extra) method, which will be deprecated in the future... I don't think that I will be upgrading to a later version of Django anytime soon, but this makes my stomache a bit unsettled.

Comment: If you are using timezones, then beware that the date of a datetime depends on which timezone your datetime is in.

Comment: Good point.  Why don't DateTimeField's contain timezone info?

Comment: If you are working timezone-aware datetimes, then timezones are usually regarded as belonging in the presentation layer. DateTimes should be in UTC internally and converted as late as possible. See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/i18n/timezones/

Answer (score 2):

I would get the queryset then sort it in the view in this case.

```
sorted(DataCollection.objects.all(), key = lambda x: x.date_modified.date(), reverse = True)
```

To sort by two keys you can use [attrgetter](https://wiki.python.org/moin/HowTo/Sorting), described in the HowTo/Sorting docs.

Comment: This looks like a very good method of doing it, but I'm having trouble with my Django DRF routing giving a "no base_name" error, so for now, I'm trying to do it all in the query itself, as I cannot return a list for some reason.

Comment: If you are in 1.10, you might be able to do something with Cast (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/database-functions/#cast) or with one of the new date functions (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/database-functions/#module-django.db.models.functions.datetime). I am in 1.9.x for the most part so I don't have any practical experience with these, however.

Comment: I'm using 1.8 so cast and a few other options went out the door. I think the right answer in the future would be to use __date whenever that becomes available.

Answer (score 0):

If your database supports datetime_to_date converting, you can try something like this:

```
DataCollection.objects.all().annotate(date_created__date=RawSQL('DATE(date_created)', ())).order_by('-date_created__date')
```

Comment: This looks almost right, but I feel like there is a pure "Django" way to do this so that I am not using Raw SQL queries.  Don't all db's have datetimefield -> datefield conversion? Shouldn't Django have some method of doing this under the hood while exposing an API to do so?

Comment: See comments for souldeux's answer. Try to use new expressions or  functions instead of RawSQL.

Comment: what do you mean by "new expressions"

Comment: I mean `Cast`, but it's a function actually.

Answer (score 0):

I think souldeux answer is probably a lot neater than this but another solution could be to query separately then join them together. I think something along these lines

```
from itertools import chain
import datetime

# get just todays data ordered by date modified
today_min = datetime.datetime.combine(datetime.date.today(), datetime.time.min)
today_max = datetime.datetime.combine(datetime.date.today(), datetime.time.max)
data_set1 = DataCollection.objects.filter(date_modified__range=(today_min, today_max)).order_by('-date_modified')

# get the rest of the data
data_set2 = DataCollection.objects.all().exclude(date_modified__range=(today_min, today_max)).order_by('-date_created')

# join it all together
all_list = list(chain(data_set1, data_set2))
```

I think django had planned to introduce a `__date` query selector i don't know if that is available yet but that might also help